# Private and default constructor in C++11 and gcc

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, private, default-constructor

Code:

```
struct A
{
    private:
    A() = default; // Version 1.
};
struct B : public A
{};

struct C
{
    private:
    C() {}; // Version 2.
};
struct D : public C
{};

int main()
{
   B b;  // Compiles          under g++ 4.7.2
   D d;  // Compilation error under g++ 4.7.2
}
```

And two situations (with gcc 4.7.2):

- If I compile this code (with the Version 1 of the A's constructor), there aren't problems.
- If I use the second constructor, gcc says me that `D::D()` is private.

Question: if I use default constructors, why do problems dissapear? If `A` has private constructors, other classes can never create instances of `A`, not even its derivated classes, irrespective of the "defaultness" of its constructor's implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This smells like a GCC **bug** to me.

Neither the whole Clause 11 about member access control nor Section 8.4.2 about defaulted constructors mention anything about *overriding* the level of accessibility of defaulted constructors.

Besides, this code does *not* compile on Clang 3.2 and Intel ICC 13.0.

On the other hand, if you comment line X, the following line will *not* do what you think:

```
B b(); // This will declare a function that accepts no argument
       // and returns a value of type B
```

If you remove the parentheses, you *should* see the problem popping up:

```
B b; // ERROR: Constructor of A is private
```

However, GCC 4.7.2 (incorrectly) raises no compilation error. It also seems this hasn't been fixed in the beta version of GCC 4.8.0 (as of build 20130127).

Comment: Neither with `line X` commented?